# What is the difference between a relational database instance and a relation instance?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database

What's the difference between a *relational database instance* and a *relation instance*? What I understand is that a relational database instance is a set of instances, which is a table in a database.  A relation instance is a record or tuple in a table.

I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct or not. Could anybody tell me the truth please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different authors may define differently, so make sure you use the same definitions as your teacher, or your team ;) I'd say a relation instance is one table (relation is just a fancy name for table), with all it's data, at a given time. A relational database instance is a bunch of table,s with their values at a given moment.

Relation = one table

Relational db = bunch of tables

Instance = values at one moment ( as opposed to the schema, which is the description of all possible values)

Comment: This does not make a clear distinction between table value & table variable. (Nor is it clear that a schema is the name & a type of the variable.)

Answer (score 2):

No your "understanding" (what's in a name) is incorrect.

A relational database is a set of [variables holding] relations.
A relation is a set of tuples.
The word "instance" adds no meaning to any of this.
A tuple is *not* a record.